# Define the 64 bit width integer in Linux

Tags: c

I try to define a 64 bits width integer using C language on Ubnutu 9.10. 9223372036854775808 is 2^23

```
long long max=9223372036854775808
long max=9223372036854775808
```

When I compile it, the compiler gave the warning message:

```
binary.c:79:19: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
binary.c: In function ‘bitReversal’:
binary.c:79: warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90
binary.c:79: warning: integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type
```

Is the long type 64 bits width?

Best Regards,

Comment: are you compiling in 64 bits mode ?

Comment: 9223372036854775808 == 2**63, but the largest 64 bit signed int is one less than that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
   long long max=9223372036854775808LL; // Note the LL
// long max=9223372036854775808L; // Note the L
```

---

A `long long` type is at least 64 bit, a `long` type is at least 32 bit. Actual width depends on the compiler and targeting platform.

Use `int64_t` and `int32_t` to ensure the 64-/32-bit integer can fit into the variable.

Comment: if I use the int64_t, what header file I need include, or I just include the stdlib.h?

Comment: You can find int64_t in 'sys/types.h' or 'stdint.h'

Comment: I have another question,If I want to printf a int64_t variable, what parameter I should pass like %d

Comment: No, not `%lld` if you use `int64_t`, %lld is for `long long`. You should use the defined constants of `stdint.h` which is in this case, `PRi64`.  `printf("my var i64 is %" PRi64 "\n", i64);`

Comment: Not true. An integer constant which is too large for int is automatically promoted to long, and if it is too large for long it is promoted to long long. L and LL are only needed to force smaller values to a larger type, for example 9600 * 32 will overflow with 16-bit int, so you need 9600L * 32 instead.

Answer (score 6):

The problem you are having is that the number you're using (9223372036854775808) is `2**63`, and the maximum value that your `long long` can hold (as a 64 bit signed 2s complement type) is one less than that - `2**63 - 1`, or 9223372036854775807 (that's 63 binary 1s in a row).

Constants that are too large for `long long` (as in this case) are given type `unsigned long long`, which is why you get the warning `integer constant is so large that it is unsigned`.

The `long` type is at least 32 bits, and the `long long` type at least 64 bits (both including the sign bit).

Comment: Yep or to use hex - max value of a signed 64-bit integer is 7FFF FFFF FFFF FFFF and OP's value is CCCC CCCC CCCC CCCC. As you say, it's too big to fit ( the compiler was even telling the OP that )

Comment: The OP's value is actually `0x8000 0000 0000 0000`, but yes.

Comment: Argh - Sorry yes. I hate cut and paste :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's will fix your problem (The LL solution looks good). But here is a recomandation :

You should use hexadecimal notation to write the maximal value of something.

```
unsigned char max = 0xFF;
unsigned short max = 0xFFFF;
uint32_t max = 0xFFFFFFFF;
uint64_t max = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

As you can see it's readable.

To display the value :

`printf("%lld\n", value_of_64b_int);`

Comment: I have another question,If I want to printf a int64_t variable, what parameter I should pass like %d

Comment: %lld or some macro defined in inttypes.h

Comment: @ronnybrendel if it's an unsigned long long int ;)

Comment: @NicolasGUILLAUME: I think you're missing `unsigned` in front of `char` and `short` and the leading `u` in `int32_t` and `int64_t`. On most platforms your definitions of `max` would have a value of `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what platform you use. If you need to know exactly what kind of integer type you use you should use types from [Stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h) if you have this include file on you system.