# Which C datatype can represent a 40-bit binary number?

Tags: c, binary

I need to represent a 40-bit binary number. Which C datatype should be used to handle this?

Comment: +1 to offset the unexplained downvotes.

Comment: Looks like the 2 downvoters netted you +3 (judging from the 5 +1's on the +1 comment) :-)

Comment: non portable, but on many TI DSPs [long is a 40-bit type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28352310/995714) so long can be used for that purpose. long on most POSIX systems has 64 bits and can also be used

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using a C99 or C11 compliant compiler, then use `int_least64_t` for maximum compatibility. Or, if you want an unsigned type, `uint_least64_t`. These are both defined in `<stdint.h>`

`<stdint.h>` usually also defines `int64_t`, but since it's not required by the standard, it may not be defined in every implementation. However:

- `int_least64_t` - at least 64 bits, and
- `int_fast64_t`  -  the fastest size in this implementation of at least 64 bits

are both required to be present in C99 and C11 (See § 7.18.1.2-3 in the C99 standard, and § 7.20.1.2-3 in the C11 standard).

---

Although C99 specifies that `long long` is [at least 64 bits on a particular machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) (§ 5.2.4.2.1), the types in [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h#stdint.h) are designed to be explicitly portable.

You can read more about integer sizes on different platforms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#cnote_b_grp_notesc).
Note that the size of integer types are a problem with the `long` data type - on 64 bit Windows, it's currently 32 bits, whereas on 64 bit linux it's 64 bits. For this reason, I believe you're  safest using the types from `<stdint.h>`

It's worth noting that some feel that `long long` is more readable. Personally, I prefer the types from `<stdint.h>`, because they allow you to say what you mean when you use them - which I find more readable. Of course, readability is often a matter of taste - and if you're working with an existing codebase, I'd just follow whatever they do :)

---

If your compiler only supports C89, then [R..'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595225/which-c-datatype-can-represent-a-40-bit-binary-number/9596246#9596246) will allow you up to 53 bits of integer precision.

Comment: I disagree.  `long long` is in fact theoretically *more* portable, because a conforming C99 or C11 implementation must provide that type whereas `int64_t` is not necessarily present.  `int64_t` should be used only if you require an exactly 64 bit two's complement type with no padding - in cases like this, where you just need "at least 40 bits" then `long long` is preferable, since it does not add unncessary restrictions.

Comment: @caf: Doesn't C99 also specify `int64_t` and family? (And as far as I know, they're still present in C11). If you don't want to specify exactly 64 bit width, then you could use `int_least64_t` or `int_fast64_t`.

Comment: @Timothy: They're optional; `int64_t` cannot exist unless unless `char` is 8-bit, and also might not exist for various other reasons. `int_least64_t` is required to exist and I suppose it's more "correct" (and less likely to be wasting space) than `long long`, but it sure is ugly...

Comment: @TimothyJones: C99 specifies them as optional (if an implementation doesn't have a type meeting the requirements, it doesn't have to provide `int64_t` - this is of course unlikely at the present time as a practical matter, which is why I said "theoretically").  `int_least64_t` is better, because it is required.  However I contend that using a smattering of `int64_t`, `int_least64_t` and `int_fast64_t` is likely to make your functions less composable than if you just used the base types.

Comment: @caf @R You're right. I've updated the answer to better reflect the standard.

Answer (score 3):

`long long` is an integer type with *at least* 64 bits. It will fit signed 40 bit values on all platforms. You can also use `unsigned long long` for unsigned values of 64 bits or more.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `long long`, which can contain 64 bits or more.  For more information, see

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Common_long_integer_sizes

[Define the 64 bit width integer in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347884/define-the-64-bit-width-integer-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are good, but if you want C89 support too, `double` will be able to store 40-bit integers exactly on all IEEE 754 conformant implementations.